# Django - Is it possible to split a single model class into two model classes, while preserving the data from before split?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django is it possible to split a single model class into two model classes, while preserving the data that was previously entered?

Initial Model:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taste_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tasty = models.BooleanField()
```

Split Models:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Fruittaste(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taste_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tasty = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step 1: create `Fruittaste` model, and run migrations (without changing `Fruit`)
- Step 2: execute the following query to populate `Fruittase`.

  ```
  data = []

  from .models import Fruit, Fruittaste

  for fruit in Fruit.objects.all():
      data.append(
      Fruittaste(
          fruit = fruit,
          taste_description = fruit.tase_description,
          tasty = fruit.tasty
      ))

  Fruittaste.objects.bulk_create(data)
  ```

Now you can delete the duplicate rows from `Fruit`, and run migrations again.

Comment: what command would you run to execute the code in Step 2. What .py file would the code in Step 2 be a part of ?

Comment: @Padoga The easiest way would be to use a django shell.  `./manage.py shell`

Comment: DONT DO THIS MANUALLY IN THE SHELL !!! Django migrations are ALSO for data migrations, so that's what should be done here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree that your solution would be better for production environments, but I don't see the harm in this when in development or while testing.  It is much more convenient than dealing with migrations.

Comment: @CalebGoodman "It is much more convenient than dealing with migrations" => no it isn't, quite on the contrary. Writing a proper data migration takes about 30s more than a throw-away script, and it __will__ be applied with the rest of the migrations when deploying in another environment (another dev env, staging, production). Also it IS part of the schema change process and history and as such belongs to migrations (and version control).  You are of course free to do however you want with your own projects (if you're the only one working on them) but please do not advise bad practices here.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any easy or single command way to do this. It can be done by:

1. Create a new model but keep the origonal model intact, i. e. don't remove any fields
2. Run a script to transfer all data to new model
3. Run tests to see if your code and views are working properly
4. Remove the unneeded and old fields in the main model at your leisure

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

1/ create your new model, leaving the original unchanged

2/ make a migration to create the model, run it, add it to your version control

3/ create an empty migration for your app, and in this migration write [the data migration code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

```
def forward(apps, schema_editor):
    # VERY important: don't import the models, 
    # get them from `app.get_model()`
    Fruit = apps.models.get("yourappname", "Fruit")
    Fruittaste = apps.models.get("yourappname", "Fruittast")

    data = [        Fruittaste(fruit=fruit,taste_description=fruit.tase_description,tasty=fruit.tasty) for fruit in Fruit.objects.all()
    ]
    Fruittaste.objects.bulk_create(data)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '000x_previous_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forward),
    ]
```

NB: depending on your dataset size, you can also write the new records to db one by one instead of collecting them in a list and send the whole to bulk_create. This will be slower, but it will eat less memory.

NB : You should add a backward migration whenever possible, but in your above case you'd have to arbitrarily choose one of the many possible tastes for each fruit so...

4/ and finally remove the now obsolete fields from `Fruit`, make and run the migration etc (nb do no forget to add your migration files to your version cotrol !!!).